# How to install a python package inside a pycharm interpreter

Tags: docker, pycharm, aws-glue

I have an AWS glue Job setup in local with pycharm professional. To run a glue job locally in windows I had to install pycharm professional and pulled the AWS glue docker image `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01` locally. And as per the official [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/), we can link that image as python interpreter to our codebase. So it will work smoothly without any dependencies issues. But I need to install some new libraries. So I tried to install it from the IDE and it's not supporting. Any other way that i can install new libraries to this image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `Appendix B: Adding Extra Libraries` in the following post: [Develop and test AWS Glue version 3.0 and 4.0 jobs locally using a Docker container](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/)